# How to format string output

Tags: xmobar

How to make cpu percentage indicators have fixed width or insert 0 when below 100.

My config for cpu

```
commands = [

        Run Cpu [
        "--template", "cpu: <total>%",
        "-L", "3",
        "-H", "50",
        "--normal", "green",
        "--high", "red"] 10
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use option `-m` to set minimum width

```
commands = [

        Run Cpu [
        "--template", "cpu: <total>%",
        "-L", "3",
        "-H", "50",
        "-m", "3",
        "--normal", "green",
        "--high", "red"] 10
]
```